# What is the difference between «nun» and «ĉi tiam»

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, correlatives

What is the difference (if any) between the correlative «*ĉi tiam*» and the German-derived «*nun*?» Or does the only difference lie in the ability to easily use the adverb form of *nun*, «*nune*,» and the adjective «*nuna*?»

Comment: One can say *ĉi-tiama* and *ĉi-tiame* for the adjective and adverb forms of *ĉi tiam*.

Comment: I'd also like to add that *ĉi tiam* is very rare - I use Esperanto every day but I can't remember the last time I heard it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"nun" and "ĉi tiam" are very different

**nun** is for referencing the **present time**.

**tiam** is for referencing a **particuliar moment**, that can be the present time, but not always. **ĉi** can indicate **proximity in time, but also in context** (where you put the focus in one particuliar time out of several that were mentionned). Even when "ĉi" is used for time proximity, it is often used for the next (or last) time, and not the present time. (For this, we use nun).

Compare:

- Li iros butikumi, kaj mi manĝos ĉi tiam (kiam li iros butikumi)
- Mi iris al la tranoktejo ĉiuvendrede, sed ĉi tiam (lastfoje) mi ne rajtis eniri

You clearly can not say:

- Li iros butikumi, kaj mi manĝos nun
- Mi iris al la tranoktejo ĉiuvendrede, sed nun mi ne rajtis eniri

Comment: Not sure if helpful, but I would say “Li iros butikumi, kaj mi manĝos tiam” (without ĉi).

Answer (score 4):

According to [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html):

> *Ĉi tiam* aŭ *tiam ĉi* ne estas praktike uzataj. Anstataŭe oni uzas **[*nun*](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/nun.html)**.
>
> **Noto:** La preciza nuanco de *ĉi tiam* estas malklara, ĉar ĝi apenaŭ estas uzata. Oni povus diskuti, ĉu *ĉi tiam* estas preferinda, kiam
>   temas pri okazoj kaj kondiĉoj, dum *nun* ordinare estas tempa. Eble
>   tempa *ĉi tiam* povas esti malpli forte ligita al la absoluta nuno ol
>   *nun*, montrante tiun tempon, kiun la rakonto atingis.

My translation:

> *Ĉi tiam* or *tiam ĉi* is practically not used. The word *nun* is used instead.
>
> **Note:** The precise nuance of *ĉi tiam* is not clear because it is hardly
>   used. One could discuss whether *ĉi tiam* is preferable when it comes
>   to circumstances and conditions, while *nun* is usually time-related.
>   Perhaps *ĉi tiam* in a time-related sense can be linked with less
>   force to the absolute present than *nun* can, showing the moment in
>   time that the story has reached.

Here are some examples from [Tekstaro](http://www.tekstaro.com/), where you can use both *ĉi tiam* and *nun*:

***Ĉi tiam*** eniris Porfirij kaj Paŭlo.

*En la kongresejon ĉiu **nun** eniris por la malferma kunsido.*

Answer (score 0):

I’d say **nun** is merely a shorter synonym for **ĉi tiam**. It’s convenient since the concept of ”now” is expressed very often in the spoken language.

As you also point out, **nun** is handy when making compounds (*la ĝisnuna direktoro* sounds better than *la ĝis-ĉi-tiama direktoro* for ”the director until now”).

You’re right that many words would be superfluous in Esperanto if it was wholly based on logic – instead of *sen*, for example, we could say *malkun* or *malper*; we don’t need *nia*  since we can easily say *de ni* etc. Personally, I think all the variation and synonyms make Esperanto a lot ”sexier”. :-)

Also, **tiam** itself is often used in a historical context: *la tiama reĝo* etc. My guess is that in some contexts **ĉi tiam** could be used with the meaning ”at this point in history” rather than ”right now”. A Google search reveals that ”ĉi tiam” is indeed sometimes used as a historical now. [Here’s an example:](https://books.google.dk/books?id=TNR7DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=%E2%80%9D%C4%89i%20tiam%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=FafYg9elRv&sig=H8dTwJAOog7ZdBNKNIoGVb2UDRU&hl=da&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsgKWXgOTaAhVLzaQKHaV3Cm84ChDoAQg6MAM) **Li havis motivitan esperon esti nomumita “ministro pri eksterlandaj aferoj” en la nova jaro. Sed bedaŭrinde ĝuste ĉi tiam nenio aparta okazis en la ekstera mondo.**

Comment: Could anyone explain the downvote? I think I did answer the question. I’ll be happy to modify it (or delete it if it doesn’t help at all).

Comment: I’ve changed my reply. Hopefully it’s clearer now?